# To Find data inside tag how to write REGEX Expression?

Tags: python, regex

I need to find data inside tag:

```py
data="<SHORT-NAME>WhlDist_Prtctd_PDU_PA_CAN_1_controller</SHORT-NAME>"
```

I tried this

```py
print(re.search('<SHORT-NAME>("^WhlDist\w.*controller$")<\/\1>', data))
```

but output is "None", expected output is

```
WhlDist_Prtctd_PDU_PA_CAN_1_controller
```

Comment: `^` means beginning of line (or whole string) which isn't right here. Similar for end of line `$`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need

```py
match = re.search(r'<SHORT-NAME>(WhlDist\w+controller)</SHORT-NAME>')
if match:
    print( match.group(1) )
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/FWGDf6/1).

*Details*:

- `<SHORT-NAME>` - a fixed string
- `(WhlDist\w+controller)` - Group 1: `WhlDist`, one or more word chars, `controller`
- `</SHORT-NAME>` - a fixed string.